# Ruby Symbols Syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, symbols

```
p [1,2,3].map(&:abs)  
p [1,2,3].map(:abs)  
p [1,2,3].reduce(&:gcd)  
p [1,2,3].reduce(:gcd)
```

Can someone pls explain why line 2 will throw an error, but not line 4.

Comment: Are the docs [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) not clear?

Comment: @CarySwoveland They are clear enough, but I didn't expect my problem to be very function specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a general syntactic thing related to `Symbol` or `Symbol#&`. It's a special case built into the implementation of `Enumerable#reduce`.

Comment: This special case precedes the symbol to proc conversion via `&` so in very old Ruby versions only line 4 is correct.